# Symbolic derivatives are being calculated numerically

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, implementation-details

*Update: (1) By V11, not sure of the exact version, the derivative `IntegerPart'` has been given a symbolic definition. (2) The numeric derivative computed has changed from an order 8 approximation (see [@acl's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29331/4999)) to an order 16 one.  I'm not sure how best to update this Q&A. -- @MichaelE2*

---

Just found the following while debugging a problem.

*Mathematica* is calculating the derivative of `IntegerPart[x]` in some odd way:

```
Plot[{IntegerPart@u, D[IntegerPart[x], x] /.x -> u}, {u, 0, 3},PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Do you know what is the violet curve in the plot above, and why *Mathematica* thinks it is the derivative of `IntegerPart[x]`?

**Edit**

Or consider for example the following:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + IntegerPart[x];
Plot[{f[x], Derivative[1][f][x]}, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Or similarly

```
Plot[{FractionalPart[x], Derivative[1][FractionalPart][x]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

What is happening here?

Comment: Strictly speaking IntegerPart[x] is not a differentiable function.

Comment: @ndroock1 It is differentiable in the space of distributions (functions like Dirac delta-function). The result roughly should be proportional to the Dirac grid - a discrete sum of Dirac delta-functions `Sum[DiracDelta[x-n],{n,-Infinity,Infinity}] - DiracDelta[x]` (no delta-function at zero). What is being seen on the plot looks like a discrete analog of this, along the lines `Sin[k x]/(Pi x)`, when `k->Infinity` - this is one well-known limiting representation of a delta-function.

Comment: @Leonid Indeed. Just try `Integrate[Derivative[1][IntegerPart][x], {x, .9, 1.1}]`. But that doesn't seem to explain the plot

Comment: @belisarius True. This seems to reflect an imperfection on the side of symbolic treatment of things related to differentiation of piecewise functions and the like. I am pretty sure that work is underway in WRI to address these issues.

Comment: @belisarius, I was not aware that `Derivative` is able to numerically approximate the derivatives of completely arbitrary user-defined functions, but now I see that this is mentioned in the docs.  The method it uses is not mentioned.  What I don't understand though is why this gives a different result than yours: `Plot[D[Quotient[x, 1], x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]`

Comment: @belisarius, if the same numerical method is used, I'd expect the numerically computed derivative of `Quotient[x,1]` to be the same as that of `IntegerPart[x]`, but apparently it's not.

Comment: @Szabolcs Nice find. Seems the period is the double there. BTW, mine is not a `completely arbitrary user-defined function`, but a Mma defined function ...

Comment: I think you should send a bug report.  Similar behaviour is expected for numerical methods, but the interval of "off" results is unacceptably large here.

Comment: @Simon Take a look at the beautiful @acl's answer. No bug. It is worse: the derivative is not implemented symbolically, and Mma is calculating it numerically at the discontinuity as a centered difference. Recipe for failure :)

Comment: @belisarius: Yeah I saw that. It's a *really* nice answer. It seems crazy since `IntegerPart` claims to be "suitable for both symbolic and numerical manipulation". It would be nice if `Floor` and `IntegerPart` were tied in with `DiracComb` properly...

Comment: I'll leave a comment here so that someone can ping me, if they have a suggestion for updating this Q&A for more recent versions of *Mma.*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've completely overhauled my answer. I believe this now answers the questions posed (why mma thinks the violet line is the derivative of `IntegerPart'[x]`).

Let's first look at `ND`, simply because its internals are easier to access and we may obtain some insight. Try:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
nd[x_, opts___] := ND[IntegerPart[u], u, x, opts]
Manipulate[
 Plot[nd[x, Scale \[Rule] s, Terms \[Rule] n], {x, 1.5, 2.5}, 
  PlotRange -> Full],
  {{s, 1}, .01, 4},
  {{n, 5}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

which allows to vary the two parameters of ND, namely the `Scale` and number of `Terms` in the method it uses. Typical results look like this:

[image]

Now, the results of `ND` are different from those of `N[D[...]]`, but allow us to guess what is happening.

In particular, `ND` is easy enough to "reverse-engineer"; all we have to do is ask nicely:

```
ND[f[u], u, x, Terms -> 2, Scale -> 1] 
(*
 ->  4. (- f[0. + x] + f[0.5 + x]) - 1. (- f[0. + x] + f[1. + x])
*)
```

and playing with the `Terms` and `Scale` gives the game up: it is a finite difference method and the points at which the function to be differentiated is evaluated are always the same (for the same `Terms` and `Scale`). Notice how the derivative being calculated is always the derivative from the right.

Now, let us check (numerically) which points are evaluated when `IntegerPart` is differentiated a la belisarius. Define

```
ClearAll[mip];
mip[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; IntegerPart[x])
ClearAll[getoffsets]
getoffsets[x_] := Reap[mip'[x]][[2, 1]] - x
```

then `getoffsets[x]` returns a list containing the offsets of the points used for evaluating the derivative from `x`. 
Thus,

```
getoffsets[.9]
(*
->{0.,0.0526316, 0.105263, 0.157895, 0.210526, 0.263158, 0.315789, 0.368421, 0.421053,
     -0.0526316,-0.105263,-0.157895,-0.210526,-0.263158,-0.315789,-0.368421,-0.421053}
*)
```

In fact, these offsets are independent of the point where the derivative is evaluated:

```
getoffsets[#] & /@ {.1, .5, .9, 1.1, 1.5, 143.} // Differences // Chop
(*
-> {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}
*)
```

(ie, the offsets from `x` of the points used for calculating the derivative at `x` are the same for all the `x` given in the list above).

Armed with this information, we can now plot the function `IntegerPart'[x]` together with vertical lines located at the points that differ from 1 (the singular point of `IntegerPart'[x]`) by any of the offsets. That is, at the vertical lines, one of the points used to estimate the derivate by mma crosses 1, where the value of `IntegerPart[x]` jumps:

```
 offsets = getoffsets[1.1];
 Plot[IntegerPart'[x],{x, .5, 1.5},
  Epilog -> (Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 10}}] & /@(1 - offsets)),
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

this gives

[image: out]

Evidently, the jumps in the plot occur whenever one of the points used to evaluate the derivative crosses 1, where `IntegerPart[x]` changes from 0 to 1. So it is completely natural that the plot has discontinuities there, given the method used to obtain the derivative.

To clarify: The numerical derivative is, effectively a sum of the form 
$\sum_i  a_i \, f(x_i)$, with $f$ the function of which we are evaluating the derivative and $x_i$ the points given by `x` plus the $i$th offset (see list above).
Whenever `x` lies on one of the vertical lines, $f(x_i)$ for one of the possible $i$ jumps from 0 to 1, hence the value of the sum jumps by $a_i$. This is indeed what we are seeing.

With a bit more work one would probably be able to work out the coefficients being used in this finite difference scheme, but I think this already answers the question. If not, let me know what is missing.

Finally, consider what happens with a step function if we allow/do not allow the plotter to look at the symbolic form of the function:

```
ClearAll[mop];
mop[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; HeavisideTheta[x])
Plot[mop'[x], {x, -.5, .5}, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[HeavisideTheta'[x], {x, -.5, .5}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

In the first plot, we prevent the plotter from seeing the symbolic expression; in the second, we do not. Here is what is produced:

[image]

So mma recognizes what is going on in the second case and plots the right thing. In the first it can't, and we get a behaviour similar to what belisarius saw.

It appears that compensating for such discontinuous functions is done "per case", is not done by looking at the numerical behaviour but by looking at the symbolic form, and `IntegerPart` isn't one of the covered cases.

**Edit** (by belisarius)

Elaborating a little over this great answer, one can find the finite differences coefficients that Mma uses for calculating the derivatives.

Assuming a centered differences method:

```
ClearAll[mip];
mip[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; IntegerPart@x)
ClearAll[getoffsets]
getoffsets[x_] := Reap[mip'[x]][[2, 1]] - x;
k = getoffsets[1.];
Rationalize[
 Table[c[r], {r, Length@k}] k[[2]] /. ToRules@
   Chop@
    Reduce[
     And @@
      Join[
       Table[N[mip'[i]] == Sum[c[r] mip[i + k[[r]]], {r, Length@k}], 
                                                   {i, 1, 2, 1/Length@k}],
       Table[c[p] == -c[p + (Length@k - 1)/2], {p, 2, (Length@k + 1)/2}]],
     Table[c[r], {r, Length@k}]], 10^-11]
(* ->
{0, 8/9, -(14/45), 56/495, -(7/198), 56/6435, -(2/1287), 8/45045, -(1/ 102960),
  -(8/9), 14/45, -(56/495), 7/198, -(56/6435), 2/1287, -(8/45045),  1/102960}
*)
```

I am too lazy to compute the actual coefficients for the eighth order difference to check if Mma is using a standard algorithm, so [`I used Google`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=8/9,%20-%2814/45%29,%2056/495,%20-%287/198%29,%2056/6435,%20-%282/1287%29,%208/45045,%20-%281/%20102960%29) to [search for them](http://pages.unibas.ch/comphys/comphys/TEACH/WS04/course.pdf)

[image]
So, everything is in place: @acl's answer is right, and **Mathematica is using the standard eighth order centered approximation for calculating derivatives** :)

Comment: @acl Very nice answer. Hope you don't mind I added a new chapter (and please check if you agree on my update!)

Comment: @belisarius it should be... I did a similar calculation yesterday but didn't have time to either clean it up or make sure it's OK. so go ahead!

Comment: @acl Yep. It's right. See update

Comment: @belisarius wow, it didn't occur to me at all to check the results by looking them up! brilliant!

Comment: @belisarius cheers! working this out was fun enough (even if it's really simple and obvious once you know it).

Comment: @belisarius actually it feels almost exactly like doing physics but without the paper- and grant-writing, political manoeuvring etc, of course... hmmm...

Comment: For reference, the method shown in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144596322507) can be used to calculate the eighth order centered derivative approximation coefficients: `With[{m = 1, s = 8, n = 16}, CoefficientList[Normal[Series[x^s Log[x]^m, {x, 1, n}]], x]]`

Answer (score 7):

The violet curve is `IntegerPart'[x]`, of course.  Here's the behavior, outside of `Plot`:

```
In[37]:= f = Function[x, Evaluate[D[IntegerPart[x], x]]];

In[42]:= f /@ Range[0.5, 1.5, 0.025]

Out[42]= {0., 0., 0., 0., -0.000184538, -0.000184538, 0.00318987, \
0.00318987, -0.0263362, -0.0263362, 0.13901, 0.13901, -0.532708, \
-0.532708, 1.61679, 1.61679, -4.29432, -4.29432, 12.5946, 12.5946, \
12.5946, 12.5946, 12.5946, -4.29432, -4.29432, 1.61679, 1.61679, \
-0.532708, -0.532708, 0.13901, 0.13901, -0.0263362, -0.0263362, \
0.00318987, 0.00318987, -0.000184538, -0.000184538, -2.75067*10^-15, \
-2.75067*10^-15, -2.75067*10^-15, -2.75067*10^-15}

In[43]:= ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image]

Beyond that, I'm not sure how the derivative is being computed.  Some sort of finite difference, perhaps.

Comment: so it looks like Mathematica is able to approximate the numerical derivative of any function. Do you know if the function that does this is accessible separately?  E.g. `N[Integrate[...]]` does the same as `NIntegrate[]`, but if we use `NIntegrate` directly, we have control over the parameters of the numerical methods used.  Is there any way to control how a numerical derivative is calculated when using `N[Derivative[1][f][x]]`?  There's `ND[]`, but it's part of a package and gives different (and much better) results.

Comment: @Szabolcs Not that I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @Szabolcs ND might give better results, but it always takes the derivative from the right (try `ND[rf[u], u, x, Terms \[Rule] 2, Scale \[Rule] s]` to see this--rf is to be undefined here). `N[D[...]]` seems to be more careful, but it seems it is using a different (finite difference) method.