# Apparent issue with derivative of FractionalPart

Tags: functions, numerics, implementation-details

This issue came to my attention from Math.SE:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015325/is-the-derivative-of-x-on-0-1-always-equal-to-1/1015342#1015342

To summarize, it appears that *Mathematica* gives erroneous results when computing the numerical value of the derivative of `FractionalPart`:  the command

```
 Plot[FractionalPart'[x], {x, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 100,
      MaxRecursion -> 8, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {-2, 4}]
```

generates the following graph:

[image]

Verification and/or explanation for this phenomenon is most welcome.

Comment: I believe it's a dup of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29329/193