# Derivation of this piecewise function introduces "numerical noise"

Tags: piecewise, calculus-and-analysis

The following function is a piecewise function. It's easy to plot with option `Exclusions->None` but it's derivative is hard to evaluate:

```
f[x_] = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/qCfdYTbd"];
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f'[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

The following works well for the `Plot`, but introduces very small and large values so I'd like a better solution to compute $f'$.

```
fp[x_] = (f[x + 10^-6] - f[x])/10^-6
```

Comment: Maybe a better definition of f:   f[x_] = Assuming[{-5 < x < 5}, 
 Simplify[Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/qCfdYTbd"] ]]?

Comment: @FredSimons Indeed, that's much better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Derivative[1, 0][Mod][x, 1]` does not evaluate symbolically, but it is evaluated numerically when plotted (see [Symbolic derivatives are being calculated numerically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29329/symbolic-derivatives-are-being-calculated-numerically) and its duplicates for more about the numerical evaluation).

```
Plot[f'[x] /. Derivative[1, 0][Mod][x_, m_] :> 
   Piecewise[{{1, Mod[x, m] != 0}}, Indeterminate], {x, -5, 5}, 
 Evaluated -> True, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is important that the replacement rule is evaluated symbolically before plotting. I used `Evaluate -> True`, but you could use `Plot[Evaluate[..], {x, -5, 5},..]`, save the derivative in a variable and then plot it, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Using Fred Simons simplification:

```
g[x_] = Assuming[{-5 < x < 5}, 
  Simplify[Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/qCfdYTbd"]]]; 
h[x_] = D[g[x], x];
Plot[h[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

Here h[x] is itself a nice piecewise function -- all the discontinuities evaluate to `Indeterminate' and so are not plotted.

Comment: Is there a reason why `D[g[x],x]` is better than `g'[x]`?

Comment: It's just different ways of writing the same thing...