# A question about PolyLog[n,x] function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I know what `PolyLog[0,-e^{-x}]` means, but I do not know what does `PolyLog^(1,0)[0,-e^{-x}]` mean. Can someone tell me what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means derivative with respect to the first variable.  Look up [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) and [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html).  Example with a general function `f`:

```
In[64]:= D[f[x, y], x]
```

[image]

Mathematica won't give any explicit symbolic form in the case of `PolyLog`, but it can compute ([estimate??](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29329/12)) numerical values.

```
Derivative[1, 0][PolyLog][2, 1] // N
(* -0.937548 *)
```