# Strange behaviour in derivative of Floor function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

The function Floor[x] is piecewise constant, hence its derivatives should be piecewise zero.

This is far from true in Mathematica

In[497]:= $Version

Out[497]= "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

The first and second derivatives in the interval $\frac{1}{2}\lt x \lt \frac{3}{2}$ are shown in these graphs

```
Plot[D[Floor[x], {x, 1}] /. x -> xx, {xx, 1/2, 3/2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "y=Floor'[x]", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[D[Floor[x], {x, 2}] /. x -> xx, {xx, 1/2, 3/2}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLabel -> "y=Floor''[x]", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

We notice that the drivatives are far from zero even over a broad range of $x$.

In the standard documentation I have found no hint of this problem.

**My question: is this a bug?**

Comment: Mathematica 10.1 is quite old. I see different results than what you describe in more recent versions of the program.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29329), by any chance?

Comment: @ user6014 Thank you for the hint. Could you perhaps show more details in an answer, i.e. how do the plots look in more recent versions?

Comment: @  J. M. is somewhat okay Sorry, what do you mean by "this"?

Comment: Did you click on the link that the "this" in my last comment was pointing to?

Comment: Thanks, click of "this" reveals that the problem is a dupilcate. In the answer provided here for M11 the bug has been removed.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in version M11, `Floor'[x]` evaluates:

```
Floor'[x] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  0 & x>\lfloor x\rfloor  \\
>  \operatorname{Indeterminate} &
>    \operatorname{True}
> \end{cases}$

Of course, this obscures the discontinuity at integer `x`. If you want to produce a derivative that can be integrated back to the original result, you can try using an equivalent [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta) representation:

```
{Plot[Floor[x], {x, 1/2, 3/2}], Plot[HeavisideTheta[x-1], {x, 1/2, 3/2}]}
```

[image]

Then:

```
D[HeavisideTheta[x-1], x]
```

> DiracDelta[-1 + x]

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[-1+x],x]
```

> HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]

Comment: @ Carl Wolf The hint on HeavisideTheta is most useful. It works also in V10.