# Why does Arg'[1. + I] return -0.5?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, complex, implementation-details

From the document we know that

> `Arg[z]` gives the gives the argument of the complex number `z`.

Then how about `Arg'[z]`? This seems to be meaningless, but *Mathematica* returns something if `z` is a non-exact number, for example

```
Arg'[1. + I]
(* -0.5 *)
```

So my question is:

1. How is the numeric value of `Arg'[z]` defined?
2. Why does `Arg'` behave like this? What's the potential usage of this behavior?

Comment: This can shed some light: `Trace[ Arg'[1. + I], TraceInternal -> True ]`

Comment: It is impossible to understand what the output from `Trace[ Arg'[1. + I], TraceInternal -> True ]` mean. May be numerics gone mad or something :)  so just change `1.0` to `1` in the example given and then `Arg` will no longer do what you show.

Comment: @Kuba Oh blinding light…

Comment: @Nasser and xzczd it looks like it calculates derivative value from set of points f
or `Arg`, but I wasn't paying too much attention.

Comment: Funny Answer,
Just ignore the method it uses to calculate and use your own method of calculation based on the result.. The reason for using this is to extended divided by two. Arg'[1./2]

Comment: Er… this answer answers which part of my question?

Comment: Just speculating, but I wonder if parts of the numerical code are working in the reals. Compare: `Limit[(Arg[1 + I + h] - Arg[1 + I])/h, h -> 0, Direction -> #] & /@ {Reals, Complexes}`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29329/symbolic-derivatives-are-being-calculated-numerically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The internal `Trace[]` Kuba advises shows calculations consistent with the numeric approximation of the partial derivative with respect to the real part:

```
D[ComplexExpand[Arg[x + I y], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], x] /. 
  x -> 1 /. y -> 1
(*  -(1/2)  *)
```

This is what *Mathematica* does with the derivative of a numeric function with approximate input.

Other examples:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
f[x_?NumericQ] := Re[x]^2;
g[x_?NumericQ] := Im[x]^2;

f'[1. + I]
g'[1. + I]
(*
  1.999999999999995`  
  -2.7506672371246275`*^-15 
*)
```

It seems like the wrong way to evaluate `Derivative`.

Comment: Funny, `Abs'[2. + I]` returns the input.

Comment: @xzczd I guess they protected `Abs'[]` from being evaluated in this way.  `Re'[]` and `Im'[]` do not evaluate, also.  Maybe they overlooked `Arg'[]`?

Answer (score 5):

The definition of the argument is $\arg(z)=\text{Im}(\ln(z))$. Its partial derivative with respect to $z$ would then be

$$
\frac{\partial \arg(z)}{\partial z}=
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\ln(z)-\ln(z^*)}{2i}
= -\frac{i}{2z}.
$$

What you see looks like twice the real part of this expression:

```
With[{z = 2. + 5 I},
  {Arg'[z], 2Re[-I/(2z)]}]

(* {-0.172414, -0.172414} *)
```

I don't know in which sense this is the "correct" answer. It could be that what is actually calculated is not the partial derivative with respect to $z$, but rather the partial derivative with respect to the *real part* of $z$:

$$
\frac{\partial \arg(z)}{\partial\text{Re}(z)}
=\frac{\partial \arg(z)}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial\text{Re}(z)}
+\frac{\partial \arg(z)}{\partial z^*}\frac{\partial z^*}{\partial\text{Re}(z)}\\
=\frac{\partial \arg(z)}{\partial z}
+\frac{\partial \arg(z)}{\partial z^*}
= -\frac{i}{2z}+\frac{i}{2z^*}
= -\frac{\text{Im}(z)}{|z|^2}
$$

```
With[{z = 2. + 5 I},
  {Arg'[z], 2Re[-I/(2z)], -Im[z]/Abs[z]^2}]

(* {-0.172414, -0.172414, -0.172414} *)
```

Comment: Er… how is derivative of $\ln(z^*)$ defined here?

Comment: Any idea why then `With[{z = 1.0 + I}, Arg'[z]]` not same as `With[{z = 1 + I}, Arg'[z]]`? Should not these give same result?

Comment: @xzczd $z$ and $z^*$ are independent variables in complex analysis, so $\partial z^*/\partial z=0$ etc.

Comment: @Nasser they do give the same result when you apply `N`: `Arg'[1 + I] // N` also gives `-0.5`.