# RootSearch warning "too small to represent as a normalized machine number"

Tags: equation-solving

[RootSearch](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) is a package for finding all roots within a range from Ted Ersek. As I test it, it is quite robust. But I also encountered some issue that I can not resolve.

I define a function

```
ClearAll[f];
f[r_?NumericQ] := 
 Sort[Re@Eigenvalues[{{3.5` - 1.6` Cos[Im[E^(I 0.) r]] - 
        2.4` Cos[Re[E^(I 0.) r]], 0, -0.07`, 0}, {0, 
       3.5` - 2.4` Cos[Im[E^(I 0.) r]] - 1.6` Cos[Re[E^(I 0.) r]], 
       0, -0.07`}, {-0.07`, 
       0, -3.5` + 1.6` Cos[Im[E^(I 0.) r]] + 2.4` Cos[Re[E^(I 0.) r]],
        0}, {0, -0.07`, 
       0, -3.5` + 2.4` Cos[Im[E^(I 0.) r]] + 
        1.6` Cos[Re[E^(I 0.) r]]}}]][[3]]
```

the plot is quite usual

[image]

Now I want to find points where the first derivative of f are zero using `RootSearch`.

If I do it as

```
roots = RootSearch[f'[t] == 0, {t, 0., 1.}];
```

there will be a warning

> General::munfl: 2.22045*10^-16 2.22507*10^-308 is too small to
> represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

And no result came out after I waited for several minutes.

However, If I do

```
roots = RootSearch[f'[t] == 0.0001, {t, 0., 1.}];
```

It finishes in seconds.

and

```
vals = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, Flatten[roots][[;; , -1]]}];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[vals]}]
```

shows

[image]

So, why is `RootSearch[f'[t] == 0, {t, 0., 1.}]` not working?

I also find as simple as `RootSearch[Sin[x] == 0, {x, 0, 100}]` will also gives precision lost warning, but it gives result immediately.

**PS:**

I found that if I change the interval to {0.1,1} then

```
RootSearch[f'[t] == 0, {t, 0.1, 1.}]
```

will work. So it is `t=0` cause the problem. Why is that?

another much simple case I just found is

```
ClearAll[g];
g[x_?NumericQ]:=x^3;
```

and

```
RootSearch[g'[x] == 0, {x, -1, 1}]
```

will not give an answer. But

```
RootSearch[3x^2 == 0, {x, -1, 1}]
```

gives answer immediately.

This is a valuable case, because [Plot based root finding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16444/4742) or `NDSolve` event locating method can not deal with this case( first derivative only touch x axis, not penetrating it)

Comment: Not related to the problem here, but I don't think it's a good idea to rely on that feature of `Derivative`, just compare: `inter = FunctionInterpolation[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 10]; Plot[{inter'@x, f'[t]}, {x, 0.1, 1}]` Other examples: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29329/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/196998/1871

Comment: @xzczd You are right. I already found ' is not reliable. It seems that it has no precision control. `ND` is controllable with `Scale` option. If this post can be solved. I actually will use `ND` for my problem for better precision.

Comment: It seems that this behaviour is the result of bug in `RootSearch` corrected in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270292/bug-in-rootsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RootSearch is an old program and changes in Mathematica since my last update cause RootSearch to have problems when looking for a root of  f[x] near x=0. There is a function Ulp2[x1,x2] in the package that determines how far it is from x1 to the nearest approximate number towards x2. Ulp2 gets hung up when x1 is machine precision zero. I might put an updated version on the Wolfram Function Repository in the coming weeks. Your problem can be simplified considerably. Change 0.0 to integer zero. Then for real r:

```
Im[E^(I*0)*r]->0
Re[E^(I*0)*r]->r
```

So your problem simplifies to:

```
Eigenvalues[{
{35 - 16 - 24*Cos[r], 0, -7/10, 0},
{0, 35 - 24 - 16*Cos[r], 0, -7/10},
{-7/10, 0, -35 + 16 + 24*Cos[r], 0},
{0, -7/10, 0, -35 + 24 + 16*Cos[r]}}/10]
```

$\left\{-\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{-35200 \cos (r)+12800 \cos (2 r)+24949},\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{-35200 \cos (r)+12800 \cos (2 r)+24949},-\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{-91200 \cos (r)+28800 \cos (2 r)+64949},\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{-91200 \cos (r)+28800 \cos (2 r)+64949}\right\}$

The output of NMinimize below shows that for any real r, you are taking the square root of a positive number in the above.

```
N@Minimize[24949-35200 Cos[r]+12800 Cos[2 r],Element[r,Reals]]
N@Minimize[64949-91200 Cos[r]+28800 Cos[2 r],Element[r,Reals]]
```

You will always have two positive and two negative eigen-values.
Next I find r where one of the positive eigen-values becomes greater than the other positive eigen-value.

```
FindRoot[24949-35200 Cos[r]+12800 Cos[2 r]==64949-91200 Cos[r]+28800 Cos[2 r],{r,0.7}]
```

(* Out[]= {r->0.722734} *)

The following f[r_] gives the same result as yours, but it provides much more insight into your problem.

```
Clear[f]
f[r_]:=Piecewise[{
  {Sqrt[ 64949-91200 Cos[r]+28800 Cos[2 r]]/100,r<0.7227342478134149},
  {Sqrt[24949-35200 Cos[r]+12800 Cos[2 r]]/100,0.7227342478134149<=r}
 }];
 Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

[image: plot of f[r]]

Comment: Hi, @Ted Ersek.  Thank you so much for answering. It is happy to see respond of the author of RootSearch:) . I definitely wish an updated version of `RootSearch`. I learned a lot by reading your example nb, and I tried hard toying with Mathematica built in functions like `FindRoot` and `FindMinimum`, currently can not find ways to surpass the robustness of your Golden-secant method for three point case.

Comment: I think Mathematica should adopt your golden-secant method :)

Comment: I created a simplified version according to your `RootSearch` rely on `FindRoot` and `FindMinimum`. It is pretty good as far as I test. But far not as delicate as yours :) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231577/4742