# How to solve this integro-dfferential equation

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I am trying to solve a complicated system of integro-differential equations, but a MWE of my problem is the following:

```
fun[rho_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := r NIntegrate[rho r1^2, {r1, 0, r}];
NDSolve[{R'[r] == D[fun[R[r], r], r], R[0] == 1}, R, {r, 0, 1}]
```

The code runs forever without producing any output: how can I solve this kind of equations?

**EDIT** a solution for *this* equation is to derive once more in $r$ and substitute back `R'[r]`, but my system is much more complicated and I do not know the initial values for the derivatives.

**EDIT2** I have tried the following code:

```
NDSolve[{R'[r]==D[r NIntegrate[r1^2 R[r1],{r1,0,r}],r],R[0]==1},R,{r,0,1}]
```

but Mathematica complaints that `r` us not a valid number for an extreme of integration.

How can I solve theis problem?

Comment: It took less than 3 minutes on my Windows machine in v12.2 to produce the resulting interpolating function.

Comment: For the toy example we can even `funa[rho_, r_] = r Integrate[rho r1^2, {r1, 0, r}]; DSolve[{R'[r] == D[funa[R[r], r], r], R[0] == 1}, R, r]`, but this isn't suitable for the real case, right?

Comment: @xzczd No the real case is more complicated

Comment: @flinty Just tested in _v9.0.1_, it takes 38 seconds to compute, and the result is correct. (Oh I forgot `Derivative` can handle things like `Derivative[1, 0][fun][1., 1.]` to some degree, related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/196998/1871 ) mattiav27, what version are you in?

Comment: @xzczd Now that I think about it: if I use `fun[R[r], r]`, does`NIntegrate` understand that `R[r]` must be evaluated at the point `r1` inside the integral?

Comment: You mean you want to compute `r NIntegrate[R[r1] r1^2, {r1, 0, r}]`? If so, your code is wrong.

Comment: @xzczd yes that is what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the integral is assumed to be inrooted, I can think out 2 approaches. First one is the relaxation method:

```
intfunc[R_, r_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[r1^2*R[r1], {r1, 0, r}, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}];

sollst = NestList[
    NDSolveValue[{R'[r] == intfunc[#, r] + r^3 #[r], R[0] == 1}, R, {r, 0, 2}] &, 
    Identity, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.402924, Null} *)

aplot = Plot[(E^(r^4/4) (-r Gamma[-(1/4)] + (r^4)^(1/4) Gamma[-(1/4), r^4/4]))/(
  4 Sqrt[2]), {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All];

ListPlot[sollst[[-1]], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]~Show~aplot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The next one is finite difference method (FDM), which is harder to code but more efficient at least in this case. I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) to facilatate the generation of difference equations:

```
Clear@int
int[expr_, {var_, 0, rlst_List}] := int[expr, {var, 0, #}] & /@ rlst
int[expr_, {var_, 0, r_?NumericQ}] := 
 With[{pos = Rescale[r, domain, {1, points}]}, 
  trap[Function @@ {var, expr}, grid[[;; pos]]]]

(* trapezoidal rule: *)
trap[f_, grid_] := 
  With[{h = -Subtract @@ domain/(points - 1)}, 
   h (Total[f /@ grid] - 1/2 (f@grid[[1]] + f@grid[[-1]]))];

eq = R'[r] == D[r intmid[r], r];
ic = R[0] == 1;

points = 80;
domain = {0, 2};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{R, intmid}[r], grid, difforder];

ae = Rest@ptoafunc[eq] /. Thread[ptoafunc[intmid[r]] -> int[r1^2 R[r1], {r1, 0, grid}]];

guess[r_] = 1;
nsol = ListInterpolation[
    FindRoot[Flatten@{ae, ic}, 
      Table[{R@r, guess[r]}, {r, grid}]][[All, -1]], {grid}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.103995, Null} *)

ListPlot[nsol, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]~Show~aplot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How should I modify the first code if `R` was a function of two variables?

Comment: @mattiav27 That depends. Can you show a specific example?

Comment: An example closer to my case could be `D[R[t,r,x],t]+D[R[t,r,x],r]+D[R[t,r,x],x]==D[r NIntegrate[r1^2 R[t,r1,x1],{r1,0,r},{x1,0,1}] ,r]` with IC: `R[t,0,x]==1` and `R[0,r,x]==1`. `t` is time. The real case is a system of 5 coupled PDE.

Comment: I forgot an initial condition `R[t,r,0]==1`

Comment: @mattiav27 Then just define 2 helper functions. (Observe the output of `D[r Integrate[r1^2 R[t, r1, x1], {r1, 0, r}, {x1, 0, 1}], r]` and think about what should be defined. ) Also, notice the calculation will be much slower for PDE system.

Comment: The problem is the function `Identity`: if I apply your code, I get the error `Identity called with 3 arguments; 1 argument is expected`

Comment: @mattiav27 Of course, `Identity` is a single-argument function. Just add an initial guess that's a multi-argument function, say `guess` where `guess[t_,r_,x_]=1`.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR I'm not sure if either of my attempts are correct, will update later.

## Attempt 1:

First SE post I've written so I apologize in advance if anything is out of order. The error messages from the OP coming from NIntegrate could be because NIntegrate usually has a hard time dealing with symbolic limits of integration, so NIntegrate was being called before a value was plugged into $r$.

I was able to get a solution to the problem in MM version 12.2 with:

```
    fun[rho_, r_] := Times[r, Integrate[Times[rho, p, p], {p, 0, r}]];
    sol = NDSolve[{R'[r] == D[fun[R[r], r], r], R[0] == 1}, R, {r, 0, 1}][[1,1,2]];
    Plot[sol[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

gives a plot that looks like:[image: Solution to an integral equation]

I would note that the solution seems to be faster without using `NumericQ` on the function, but depending on your application, you may or may not wish to keep it there.

I was able to get two different analytical solutions, the first being:

```
    a1 = DSolve[{R'[r] == D[r * Integrate[q * q * R[q], {q, 0, r}], r], R[0] == p}, R[r], r]
```

and a more refined version over the unit interval:

```
    a2 = DSolve[{R'[r] == D[r * Integrate[q * q * R[q], {q, 0, r}], r], R[0] == p}, R[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

yielding the expressions:
\begin{equation}
R\left( r\right)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} e^{\frac{r^{4}}{4}}p\left[ r\;\Gamma\left( -\frac{1}{4}\right) -\left( r^{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}} \Gamma\left( -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{r^{4}}{4}\right) \right]
\end{equation}

where $\Gamma\left(\cdot\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(\cdot,\cdot\right)$ are intended to mean the gamma and upper-incomplete gamma functions respectively, and on the unit interval:

\begin{equation}
R\left(r\right)=\frac{1}{4}e^{\frac{r^{4}}{4}}p\left[E_{5/4}\left(\frac{r^{4}}{4}\right) + 2\sqrt{2}\;r\;\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]
\end{equation}

where $E_{n}$ is the exponential integral function.

To be true(er) to the original problem though, I was able to use:

```
    mfun[rho_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := r NIntegrate[rho r1^2, {r1,0,r}];
    msol = NDSolve[{R'[r] == D[mfun[R[r], r], r], R[0] == 1}, R, {r,0,1}][[1,1,2]]
```

which when plotted gives the same visual as shown above.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as mentioned in the comment above, the `NDSolve` solution is incorrect, you're calculating `Integrate[q * q * R[r], {q, 0, r}]` rather than `Integrate[q * q * R[q], {q, 0, r}]` in this case, and if you `Show` the plots together, the difference between `sol` and `a1`/`a2` is obvious.

Comment: I derived a second solution, will try to add in the AM.

Comment: @NathanWhite Very interesting answer! I'm struggeling to derive a pure numerical answer using `NDSolve&NIntegrate`  but didn't succeed. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**extended**

If I understand the question right, OP is looking for a **numerical solution** where integral isn't known analytically.

First we need a function definition of the integral part, where a function `ip` is passed as argument.

```
int[ip_][r_?NumericQ] :=Module[{u}, NIntegrate[u^2 ip[u], {u, 0, r}]  ]
```

Differentiating the integralequation "manually" (don't know why `NDSolve` can't handle `D[r  int[Function[{r}, R[r]]][r ],r]` ) gives the ode

```
RR = NDSolveValue[{R'[r] == int[Function[{r}, R[r]]][r ] + r^3 R[r],R[0] == 1}, R, {r, 0, 2}]
Plot[RR[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The solution agrees quite well (also in the extended domain `0<r<2` , see @xzczd  comment, Thanks) with the analytical one in @Nathan White`s answer:

```
sol=DSolve[{R'[r] == D[r * Integrate[q * q * R[q], {q, 0, r}], r], R[0] == 1}, R[r],  r ]
Plot[{RR[r], R[r] /. sol}, {r, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"r","R[r]"},PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Dashed, Red}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is wrong. `NDSolve` has actually parsed your ODE to something amount to `R'[r] == Integrate[u^2 R[r], {u, 0, r}] + r^3 R[r]`. And if you enlarge the domain to `{r, 0, 2}` in `NDSolve`, you'll see it's still different from the analytic solution.

Comment: @xzczd Astonishing, thanks. I only checked the range `{r,0, 1}`. That means, `NDSolve` parses the wrong ode.  I have already noticed  that the function call only works in the form `int[Function[{r}, R[r]]][r ] ` .Variants `int[Function[{u}, R[u]]][r ] ` or  `int[R][r]` or `int[R[#]&][r]` fail   .

Comment: @xzczd I modified the definition `int[ip_][r_?NumericQ] :=Module[{u}, NIntegrate[u^2 ip[u], {u, 0, r}]  ]`. Solution now also agrees with the analytical one in the range `{r,0,2}`!

Comment: Well, did you forgot to modify the domain of `NDSolve` or `Plot`? The solution is still wrong according to my test…

Comment: No I modified the domain. I 'll add the comparison.

Comment: …What value did you use for `p`?

Comment: ...`p=1` copy paste problem..

Comment: Can't reproduce in v12.2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTbCf.png  which version are you in? Have you tested with a fresh kernel? (Update: can't reproduce in v12.3, either. Here's the Wolfram cloud notebook: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/07fa24fd-e91b-46e7-83ba-e2ab2771539c )

Comment: My version is v12.2 too. Later I'll try to run your notebook in the cloud.

Comment: Your solution is the right one! With increasing `r` the numerical solution gets worse, perhaps a problem of `NIntegrate` ?

Comment: Actually `Module[{u},…` doesn't have any effect here, `NDSolve` still parses the ODE to something amount to `R'[r] == Integrate[u^2 R[r], {u, 0, r}] + r^3 R[r]`. Try: `tst = NDSolveValue[{R'[r] == Integrate[u^2 R[r], {u, 0, r}] + r^3 R[r], R[0] == 1}, 
   R, {r, 0, 2}];

Plot[{RR[r], tst[r]}, {r, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]`