# Iteration limit exceeded

Tags: map, iteration

I am trying to adapt the following piece of code (coming from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246172/8822) answer):

```
Clear@int
int[expr_, {var_, 0, rlst_List}] := int[expr, {var, 0, #}] & /@ rlst
int[expr_, {var_, 0, r_?NumericQ}] :=  With[{pos = Rescale[r, domain, {1, points}]}, trap[Function @@ {var, expr}, grid[[;; pos]]]]
```

to my real case in which I have three variables, but I get the error

> Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.

I have tried to mess around with the code but I could not find a solution. Here is what I have now:

```
Clear@int
int[expr_, {var_, -81/100, rlst_List}, {var2_, 1/10, \[Theta]lst_List}, {var3_, 0, [Phi]lst_List}] :=  int[expr, {var, -81/100, #1}, {var2, 1/10, #2}, {var3, 0, #3}] & @@ {rlst, \[Theta]lst, \[Phi]lst}
int[expr_, {var_, -81/100, r_?NumericQ}, {var2_, 1/10, \[Theta]_?NumericQ}, {var3_, 0, \[Phi]_?NumericQ}] := With[{pos1 = Rescale[r, domain1, {1, points}], pos2 = Rescale[\[Theta], domain2, {1, points}], pos3 = Rescale[\[Phi], domain3, {1, points}]}, trap[Function @@ {var, var2, var3, expr}, grid1[[;; pos1]],  grid2[[;; pos2]], grid3[[;; pos3]]]]
```

`trap` calculates an integral with the trapeziodal rule, tell me if you need that piece of code too.

**EDIT** I haven't tried the suggestion by @flinty, but I tried to use smaller lists, down to just one element, but the problem remains, so I think that there is actually some issue with the code.

**EDIT2** I have now tried to set `$IterationLimit` to $10^6$ but I still get the error

**EDIT3** Now that I think of it, the original code `Map`s the list into `int`, this is what I should do in my modified version, not `Apply`: I have to redefine the function `int` from scratch I think...

**EDIT4** I think I have a solution, probably not the best one, but a solution:

```
int2[r_Real, \[Theta]_Real, \[Phi]_Real] :=  int2[r, \[Theta], \[Phi]];
int2[r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := int[r1^2, {r1, -81/100, r}, \[Theta]1, 1/10, \[Theta]}, {\[Phi]1, 0, \[Phi]}];
MapThread[int2, {grid1, grid2, grid3}]
```

It gives as output a list like the original one. The problem is that I have to define many `int` one for each integrated function, but that can be done easily....

Comment: Did you try to increase the [`$IterationLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$IterationLimit.html) ?

Comment: @flinty no. So there is nothing actually wrong with the code?

Comment: Your observation in **EDIT3** is correct. `int[expr, {var, -81/100, #1}, {var2, 1/10, #2}, {var3, 
    0, #3}] & @@ {rlst, \[Theta]lst, \[Phi]lst}` is wrong, think carefully about what I am doing with the `Map` in my original implementation, you should never modify code blindly.

Comment: @xzczd I have modified the code so that `int` takes in input `Reals` not lists and it works on numbers from the grids, now I have to find a way to `MapThread` or something the lists...

Comment: @xzczd see my edit I think I did something