Behavioral difference between ways of calculating antiderivatives
Disclaimer: I am fairly new to Mathematica.
The context: I am solving a physics problem that iterates recursively. It is an approximation to electrodynamics in the following sense: It starts with a certain charge distribution and an electric field. The electric field moves the charges and the new charges' position create a new electric field. Use this new electric field to find the solution to find the next position of the charges. For the more physics inclined, I am studying the back-reaction of a scalar field in a background electric field. I am only considering one spatial dimension.
The point is that at each iteration I need to calculate the electric potential $A_0$ given the charge distribution $\rho$ , which is fairly easy to do. In this problem, the induced electric potential can be calculated through integrating the charge distribution twice, i.e. : $$\frac{d^2A_0}{dx^2} = -\rho \implies A_0 = -\int\int\rho,$$
i.e. Solving Poisson's equation for a static charge distribution.
Right now my code works by solving Poisson's differential equation,
A0inducedNew = 
  Module[{f}, 
   NDSolveValue[{f''[z] == -\[Rho][z], f[0.5] == 0., f'[0] == 0.}, 
    f, {z, 0, 1.5}]];

The specific boundary conditions for the potential are of course set by the problem.
However, in this case, $\rho$ is an interpolation function, and I would like to use the fact that calculating  Derivative[-2][\[Rho]] is apparently much faster,
 by a factor of 10⁵.
For some reason, when calculating the new potential as
A0inducedNewOffset = Derivative[-2][\[Rho]];
A0inducedNew = -A0inducedNewOffset[#] + A0inducedNewOffset[1/2] &;

the behavior of the code is much more different. Now it takes much much longer, and also the recursive procedure takes many more steps to converge.
Is there anything wrong I am doing in the implementation of the antiderivative?

Hello, welcome to MMA.SE, then…Er…What's the question here? Do you mean you're facing performance issue? Also, you need to show us the complete code sample, currently the definition of ρ is not given, so it's hard to give advice.

@DanielHuber The syntax is correct, I believe. OP just hasn't shown us the definition of ρ, which is a function, if I understand the question correctly.

yes, exactly. I could include a MWE, but to reproduce this error one needs the whole physical context leading to about 500 lines code. The code runs just fine with both ways of calculating A0, but even though calculating A0inducedNew is way faster, it leads to incredibly slower overall runtimes.

Well, if the sample is 500 lines long, then I'm afraid it's off-topic here… Anyway, let me try guessing: does the troublesome code involve Derivative of A0inducedNew?

Exactly. It's not troublesome in itself. It just gives weird different behaviors of the whole thing, and I would expect calculating A0 = Derivative[-2][rho]; to be much faster (or at least equivalent to A0 = NDIntegrate[f'' = -\rho].

Then I guess you're facing this issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29331/1871 In short, except for some special cases (like InterpolatingFunction[...]), Derivative will use a rather inaccurate way for calculating the derivative of black-box function. Your A0inducedNew is such a function. To avoid this, one possible solution is to build a InterpolatingFunction[...] from the original data. See e.g. this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337/1871

A quick example: func = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]; coord = func["Coordinates"][[1]]; values = func["ValuesOnGrid"]; newfunc = ListInterpolation[-values + func[1.5], {coord}]

I see. I am now trying to solve the other issue (to which you just replied to), the one about recursion. Thank you, I will check this out (and most importantly check runtimes).

Oops, I retract the line "Your A0inducedNew is such a function". Just found that Derivative is clever enough to handle A0inducedNew properly i.e. the accurate method will be used to calculate the derivative. But still, building an InterpolatingFunction[...] using my method above should reduce the overhead and make the evaluation of A0inducedNew faster.

Marvelous. I will get back at you when I try this out
